# Allow search for any question with Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

It will be very good if this app allows us to (also) browse old questions. We see only Relevant, Active, Vote and Newest so we can't browse older questions which already had solutions. We don't use this app just for reading active and unanswered questions, but also to learn with it, so please let us search for any question available (like in normal web browsers).

Comment: So what you're saying is the Android app doesn't have a search bar?

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq there is no paging, so no way to easily reach old questions.

Comment: This seems like more of a request for a more specialized filter, which actually doesn't sound like a horrible idea (even if kind of narrowly-scoped in the context of this request).

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq, Android app for this site, (I'm using version 1.0.89 ). Problem is not search bar but filter, suppose the solution you need is found in question asked in 2009! you have to switch to other browser, which is boring!